# Decoradores en python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una pregunta en cuanto a los decoradores en python3, se que son,para que son, como se usan (su sintaxis), eso lo tengo claro.

se poner algo muy básico como un print antes y después de la función a decorar, pero y si en vez de un simple print deseo iniciar un servidor socket antes y después de la función a decorar?  La función a decorar lo que hace es conectarse justo después de ser creada, pero como esta aun no se ha abierto un socket, es ahí donde entraría el decorador para ampliar su funcionalidad, pero que creen? no he podido lograrlo, si me dieran un ejemplo sencillo se los agradecería.

Que tengan buen día.